# Android Cordova Facebook error "Session was closed and was not closed normally" even if correct Hash Key

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, cordova-plugins

I used below plugin to integrate faceBook in my Cordova project.
[Cordova FaceBook plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin)

After Login in FaceBook Dialog i am getting error "**Session was closed and was not closed normally**" , even if i given correct hash key.

Can any one please help me how to resolve this. i am struggling a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with key has. If you have Android Studio installed and you can see logcat when you try to login there will be an error.Invalid key hash. The key hash xxxxxxxxxx does not match any stored key hashes.Configure your app key hashes at.....".Copy this xxxxxxxx key to your development hask key on your facebook app's setting page . and this should resolve "invalid key hash errors"